# Custom camera class in android

Tags: android, android-camera

I create a CameraSurfaceView.java

And i added cameraSurfaceView in containerView.

Also, i input permission and feature.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

But it doesn't work.

How do i fix this?

here is my sample code,

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/cameraPreview"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    FrameLayout containerView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);

        containerView= (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);

        CameraSurfaceView cameraSurfaceView = new CameraSurfaceView(MainActivity.this);
        containerView.addView(cameraSurfaceView);
    }

}
```

CameraSurfaceView.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CameraSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
Camera camera = null;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
boolean previewing = false;

public CameraSurfaceView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    surfaceHolder = getHolder();
    if (surfaceHolder != null) {
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    }
}


@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    if(previewing){
        camera.stopPreview();
        previewing = false;
    }

    if (camera != null){
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
            previewing = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    camera = Camera.open();
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
    previewing = false;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: try changing the line `camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);` to `camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);` in `surfaceChanged` method.

Comment: i change camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder); to camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder); in surfaceChanged. but it doesn't work. what is wrong my code.

Comment: It does not work… does it throw an exception? Is surfaceChanged() called? Isn't it called twice?

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass camera object also in `CameraSurfaceView`

```
 public CameraSurfaceView(Context context,Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        this.camera = camera;
        surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        if (surfaceHolder != null) {
            surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        }
    }
```

In you main activty you need to open the camera //initialize,

```
private Camera mCamera;

    CameraSurfaceView cameraSurfaceView = new CameraSurfaceView(MainActivity.this,mCamera);
```

Comment: I open a camera and pass it, but it doesn't works. like this : onCreate() { mCamera = Camera.open(); }

Comment: check this example it will help http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/hardware/camera-hardware/android-camera-example/